# TextBlock not updating when a function is executing in windows phone app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, textblock

I am new to C# and currently I am developing a windows phone app in C#, in which I need to print some callback event messages on the UI. I am using TextBlock to display the messages. During a function calls I am getting multiple callback events from the lower level stack which I need to display on the UI. But UI seems to block till the function returns and the TextBlock doesn't update. When the function returns the TextBlock UI is updated with the last callback message which was generated during the function call.

I tried by creating a BackgroundWorker thread and updating the UI, but still UI blocks till current function in main thread returns. Somebody please guide me.

Comment: You may want to check the Async/Await functionality of the .Net framework. Also, some code showing the background worker functionality and text block would really help.

Comment: @Nahuel thanks for the quick response. Can you please give me some reference or any example that can suite to my situation. I am completely lost in searching for the answer.

Comment: [Try this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) and see if it helps.